# Problem with Bind9 initial configuration

Tags: bind9

I´m new using Bind 9. I have follow a tutorial on web, and i dont know why its not working....
i have configured this files:

```
named.conf.local :

//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";   
zone "ejemplo.com" {  
type master;  
file "/var/lib/bind/db.ejemplo.com.hosts"; 
};

db.ejemplo.com.hosts :
;
; BIND Database file for ejemplo.com zone 
;    
@ IN SOA ejemplo.com. hostmaster.ejemplo.com. (
2011091601 ; serial number
3600 ; refresh
600 ; retry
1209600 ; expire
3600 ) ; default TTL
;    
IN NS ns.ejemplo.com.
IN MX 10 mail.ejemplo.com.
IN TXT ( "v=spf1 mx ~all" )
;    
localhost A 127.0.0.1
ns A 192.168.200.250
mail A 192.168.200.251
www A 192.168.200.252
```

This is my `resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

when i try to do `host ejemplo.com` its result is:

```
Host ejemplo.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

Comment: @SatoKatsura , could you put the example? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing or knowing more of your set-up, I'll take a few guesses :]

Check for the options in `named.conf.local`

```
options {
    // listen-on is the IP of the server that is 
    // accessible to the network. This allows all
    // machines on the 192.168.200.* network to use
    // "this" DNS. 
    listen-on { 192.168.200.250; };
    // forwarders allows this DNS to perform domain 
    // name look-ups for domains not managed by bind 
    forwarders { 127.0.0.1; };
}
```

For `db.ejemplo.com.hosts` add an `A` record. Your set-up is a little different from what I do so this could be slightly wrong.

```
ejemplo.com IN A 192.168.200.250
```

Or possibly:

```
@ IN A 192.168.200.250
```

In `/etc/resolv.conf`, set the IP for your server first then add your ISP DNS as well so bind can find domains it does not manage.

```
nameserver 192.168.200.250
nameserver IP.OF.YOUR.ISP.DNS
nameserver ANOTHER.ISP.DNS
```

You also need to restart bind for these changes to be seen.

After this your server (the machine with bind running on it) should be able to find `ejemplo.com`. If you set the primary DNS on machines on the LAN to `192.168.200.250` they will be able to find `ejemplo.com` as well AND they should be able to see everyone beyond your LAN too.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `db.ejemplo.com.hosts` file has no `A` record for `ejemplo.com`. It does have `MX`, `NS`, and `TXT` records for that name, but since you run `host` with no argument, it searches for the `A` record. You need to add that `A` record (or add, e.g., `-t mx` to your host command).

Second though, the `SERVFAIL` message in the host output means something is wrong with your configuration. Your post doesn't contain the logs, so I can't say what. Check your syslog, and see if you find any log entries from `named`; if you can't figure them out, post them here.